# Simple HTML DOM:Cannot fetch ant pagination

Tags: php, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I am trying to scrape a website to estimate number of products against provided keyword. to accomplish this task instead of scrolling through each page and count the products manually, all that I want to do is to find the last page displayed in `ant-pagination` as `ant-pagination-item` and multiply it with total number of products on one page to get an estimated number of products.
I have written it using `simple_html_dom.php` this is what my code looks like.

```
<?php
    require_once('simple_html_dom.php');
    $query = $_POST['q'];
    $url = "https://www.daraz.pk/catalog/?q=".$query;
    $html = file_get_html($url);

    if (!empty($html)) {
        $pages = $html->find("li.ant-pagination-item",-1);  
        $pages = html_entity_decode($pages->plaintext);
    }

    else {
        echo "Something went wrong";
    }

    echo "<div>";
    if (isset($pages)){
        echo "FOUND $pages";
    }
    echo "</div>";
```

I am passing a query through form and appending it to `$url` the problem is when the code runs it only shows `FOUND` which means `$pages` is set. I tried to check if this only happens with pagination or anything else too and found out that only pagination is showing such behavior and I can't figure out a single way to solve it.
It would be a great help if someone could help me understanding the mistake I am making. you could try visiting [This Link](https://www.daraz.pk/catalog/?q=test) and there will be 102 pages but this script wont return `FOUND 102` but only `FOUND` is printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible due to dynamic behavior of page. since the scraper's library is in php and it only extracts the content of pages as soon as it is loaded, ignoring all the dynamic content, dependent on JavaScript events. Solution to this problem is to use `SimpleHTMLDOM` with `CasperJS` and `PhantomJs`.
Casper will allow to use delays while the page finishes loading making it easier to scrape dynamically loaded components.